# fatal error: 'plist/Node.h' file not found error in C++ in VScode in Mac

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to run a simple hello world program in C++ from VSCode(MacOS). But i'm getting this issue

I've tried making a new tasks.json with the following json given below (It was auto generated via VSCode).

My g++ and clang++ both installed as i checked the versions on terminal.

I have also done :  xcode-select --install in my terminal.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: We have no idea. Where is it supposed to be found? Also, a simple hello world program shouldn't be needing anything called `plist/Node.h`. Do you have this mentioned in the source code?

Comment: I just have one import #include <iostream> also it says its a dependecy of iostream

Comment: Can you compile your file from the terminal?

Comment: Its giving the same error.

Comment: Then your compiler is not installed correctly. VSCode is irrelevant.